# Django checking if message.tags contains string always return false

Tags: django, jinja2

I have set `extra_tags` in my view, but when I check for the target tag in my template, the condition always evaluates to false.

View:

```py
messages.success(request, "success")
messages.info(request, "you can undo this", extra_tags="undo")
```

Template:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  {{ message.extra_tags }}
  <li>
  {% if 'undo' in messages.extra_tags %}
    this has undo in tags
  {% else %}
    {{ message }}
  {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This result in this HTML:

```
* success
* you can undo this
```

This is what I expect

```
* success
* this has undo in tags
```

(1) I have confirmed that the "undo" tag is output from `{{ message.extra_tags }}`

(2) I have tried `messages.tags` instead of `messages.extra_tags` but neither method reaches the true branch in the if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition seems wrong. Since you're iterating over each message coming from the messages framework, you'll have to check the `extra_tags` on the `message` and not the `messages`.

So, your template will become:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  {{ message.extra_tags }}
  <li>
  {% if 'undo' in message.extra_tags %}
    this has undo in tags
  {% else %}
    {{ message }}
  {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Notice here, that we're checking the current `message` object that is being iterated on.